# FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE, retry in 80s

Tags: android, firebase

FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE, retry in 80s

I am trying to Authenticate using Firebase. The above Error code will shown 
Below is my Gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I had same issue, I solved this, Just try to run your app from different devices and test if token  received in Log. This issue arises due to google play service not updated in particular device. Also add this dependency ' classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'' in Project level gradle. In app level gradle add this dependency ' compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0''. Thanks

Comment: okay @TechnoGeek i'll try this.. thanks for your Response